# Cannot change/set Div background-color in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a  with its own background-color. 
The  is rendering, but the background-color is not being changed

```
import React from 'react'

class Color extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);    
      }

    mkColor = () => {
        return <div style="background-color: blue;">TEST!!!!</div>       
    }

    render() {
        return this.mkColor()
    }
}

export default Color
```

How am I screwing this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [use objects for style](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style).

```js
mkColor = () => {
        return <div style={{backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>TEST!!!!</div>       
    }
```

Comment: Note the camel case too. That's a thing. It's just familiar enough to bite you.